# C++ Tutorial seems wrong

Tags: c++

I just wanted to ask [about this tutorial.](http://www.suntimebox.com/raspberry-pi-tutorial-course/week-7/day-4-beginning-c-plus-programming/)

I don't get it.  The code they write is like this:

```
intmain() {
    cout << "Hello World!\n";
    return0;
}
```

Now, I'm really really new to c++, but surely it should be:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Or is there some fancy way of writing c++ that I don't understand?  The code written in this tutorial won't compile for me.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit thanks.  But am I right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: did you ask the author of the tuturial ? imho it is better to contact them before posting their mistakes in public

Comment: and btw don`t trust any tutorial. There are just to many of them and it is just not possible that all of them are good.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it refers to a tutorial on a different site and mainly attracts critics on that tutorial whose authors most likely had good intentions.

Answer (score 11):

You are correct; that "tutorial" is *chock full* of formatting mistakes.

Many, many, many C++ tutorials are wrong. Don't trust the word of some randomer on the internet; use [a proper, peer-reviewed book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 2):

They clearly had problems with spaces and quotes when they copy-pasted their code.

As a result, their code is not copy-paste ready.

I believe it should be:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes it's weird really, because theres comments at the bottom of people saying "Thanks! Works great!" sort of thing.  I don't get it.

Comment: Maybe the formatting was changed by someone who does not know `c++` after the article was published. Although that does not explain the missing std::

Answer (score 1):

> Or is there some fancy way of writing c++ that I don't understand?

Well, there still could be nasty things presumed like using c-preprocessor macros<sup>1</sup>:

```
#define intmain int main
#define return0 return 0
```

---

But I have to agree with @Lightness, just don't trust random sources for learning.

A good one for c++ I use at an almost daily basis for getting a reliable reference is [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/).

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>I'd escalate seeing such to my boss as blatant incompetence, and recommend to fire the author that wrote such code.</sub>

Comment: That's a reference site; good for lookup but not for learning.

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously, you need to have spaces between return 0; and int main().

Now, lemme go ahead and explain the std:: for you. std is a 'namespace'. Basically, its used to group similar code together, to avoid name collisions. The 'standard' (std) namespace includes well, the basic C++ features. In new(ish) versions of C++, you need to specify the namespace you take your functions from.

You could, do "using namespace std;" at the beginning, or specify the namespace individually, like in your corrected code, for each standard function you use.

Comment: You should never have `using namespace std;`  [***Link***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @abelenky True, but it doesn't really matter for trivial pieces of code.

Comment: It matters **more** for trivial pieces of code.  It brings in the massive `std::` namespace for your code to use 1 or 2 items.  When another developer reads the code, it tells them *nothing* new. (all code uses `std::`, but it still doesn't tell them what parts get used)

Comment: imho `using namespace std;` is one the worst habit of tutorial writers. It merely saves you from writing 4 letters (which actually I personally see as a downside) and makes beginners believe that it would be good practice